# .NET Core MarshalByRefObject equivalent

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Is there an equivalent of the [`MarshalByRefObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.marshalbyrefobject(v=vs.110).aspx) class for .NET Core?

I need a reference type that can be used as a identifier. The identifier have to be a reference type because I need to map a list of identifiers to a list of instances in a [`ConditionalWeakTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757(v=vs.110).aspx) that only accept reference types as key. A [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) can't be used in my case, so I can't use something like a GUID.

I have to reproduce this piece of code https://github.com/ninety7/DbContextScope/blob/master/src/DbContextScope.EfCore/Implementations/DbContextScope.cs.

Comment: I don't understand what are your actual requirements. `MarshalByRefObject` is most commonly used for communicating across app domains, which don't exist in .Net Core. Why can't you use a simple `class`?

Comment: I have to reproduce this piece of code https://github.com/ninety7/DbContextScope/blob/master/src/DbContextScope.EfCore/Implementations/DbContextScope.cs

Comment: Given the comment at the bottom of https://github.com/ninety7/DbContextScope/blob/master/src/DbContextScope.EfCore/Implementations/DbContextScope.cs , why can't you use a ToString'ed GUID ?

Comment: It was my first attempt but the ConditionnalWeakTable accepts reference types only like mentioned in my question.

Comment: string is a reference type @MaximeGélinas - although it does lack reference equality (https://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/12/conditionalweaktable.html) . Is that what you meant by reference types?

Comment: Oh god thanks I only tried with a GUID and I was sure that a String is a value type. My bad..